# Bootstrap navbar jerks when switching to affix

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a standard Bootstrap navbar, where after scrolling 50px, jQuery adds affix as shown:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#mainNav').affix({offset:{top:0}})
</script>
```

Since this switches the navbar from `position:relative` to `position:fixed`, it causes a jerk when the content below the navbar jumps to the top of the screen to fill the space.

I've been playing around and am unable to prevent this jump from happening or at least making it smooth. I've tried to make the navbar fixed from the beginning and adding a `margin-top` for the height of the navbar, but unfortunately, this doesn't work correctly.

CSS

```
.navbar-default {
    background:#fff!important;
    border:0;
    border-top:4px solid #01203F;
    height:110px;
    border-radius:0;
    margin:0;
}
@media(min-width:768px) {
    .navbar-default {
        -webkit-transition: all 1s;
        -moz-transition: all 1s;
        transition: all 1s;
        border-bottom: none;
        z-index:10001!important
    }

    .navbar-default.affix {
        width:100%;
        background: #0E2A45!important;
        border-bottom: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by placing the navbar in a wrapper.

The navbar was 110px height, so added:

```
<div class="nav-wrapper">
<div class="navbar affix">...</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.nav-wrapper {min-height:110px}
```